# How do i prevent this error while changing main activity file name in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

[when i try changing the MainActivity file name to example(NoteKeeper_Activity error occurs on the code as the screenshot shows)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvf3L.png)

Comment: That is because no such file exists

Comment: You renamed the file, but you didn't rename the class. Right-click on MainActivity -> Refactor -> Rename and change the name to NoteKeeperActivity. The file name should be the same as the activity inside, so change the file name to NoteKeeperActivity as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.